# how to run maven command line with specified spring profiles?

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I'm running spring boot app with mvn command line. how can I active the specified spring profile? I tried this but with no luck:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="some parameters" -Dspring.profiles.active=schedule
```

Comment: what is your problem? Any exception? Please provide some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `run.profiles`, for example:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="some parameters" -Drun.profiles=schedule
```

More details [in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-profiles.html):

> The active profiles to use for a particular application can be specified using the profiles argument
>
> The profiles to enable can be specified on the command line as well